# Rendering Dynamic Components in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue.js

I'm trying to render a dynamic component in vue.js by faking an ajax call by using set timeout. It should register a new component then set it in the view! I'm using vue.js 1. Please show me a solution as to how I can get this working please.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>test dynamic components</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div v-component="{{currentView}}"></div>


 <script src="vue-v1.js"></script>
 <script>
    //Create the 'default' component
    Vue.component("default", {
        template: '<div>This should be replaced (and will be in 2 seconds)</div>'
    });

    //Create the parent ViewModel
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: "body",
        data: {
            currentView: "default"
        }
    });

    //Pretend to load the data from the server
    //This would actually be $.get("/url", data, function(){...});
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        
        //Create the new component using the template we received
        Vue.component("BoardFeed", {
            template: '<div>Template returned from server, what I really want</div><br>And directives work too:<div v-repeat="items">{{$value}}</div>',
            data: function () {
                return {
                    items: [1, 2, 3]
                };
            }
        });
        
        //And then change the page to that component
        vm.currentView = "BoardFeed";
    }, 2000);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ISSUE:**

I'm using Vue.js 1 and I can't interpolate the view of my component! I don't think using the `v-component` even is used anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine with Vue.js 1 when you make two small changes:

1. Use `<component :is="currentView"></component>` to include the components. `v-component` has been removed quite some time ago in [0.12.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/0.12.0).
2. Use `<div v-for="value in items">{{value}}</div>` to iterate over an array. `v-repeat` has been deprecated in [1.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1200).

Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0nk4f1ur/).